# Leaving minecarts without moving them

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When getting out of a free standing minecart (not on a rail), is it possible to do so without moving (pushing) it at all? If so, how?

Comment: Never mind, disregard my answer - I didn't notice the "free standing minecart" part (I tested my answer and it bumps the cart). Actually, I tried Kevin's and my answer (heh) and I can't manage to not nudge it). Just out of curiosity, why would you want to get out of a minecart without moving it?

Comment: it is supposed to get boosted onto a rail by an adjacent rail, free standing means it is floating on a field of pressure plates ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place another minecart in a 1x1 hole within reach of your derailed minecart and just hop into it with a right-click.

(not my idea, shamelessly stolen from Minecraftaddict's YouTube, [see his explanation](http://www.youtube.com/user/Minecraftaddict#p/u/22/Iky-lDIymSU))

Comment: Now that is awesome! This doesn't even seem to touch the unrailed cart. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since [version 1.3.1](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history#Gameplay_2), players are moved away from minecarts when exiting automatically, so as long as there is a valid block to stand on once you've exited the minecart should not move.

Answer (score 2):

Exit the cart, jump straight up, then move sideways once your (invisible...) feet are above the cart. This is easier if there's a block or even a slab next to the cart to jump onto.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works if the cart is on a track.

Comment: Then you're not doing it right :-)

Comment: Can you find a part of a video where this is happening? I seem to fail on that part :p

Answer (score 0):

We kind of solved the problem by placing a block on the other side of the track, so that it gets pushed against a wall, which does not move it drastically. It worked quite well for all users of my train station. The advantage is that it is quite easy to use and thus hard for somebody to break it (this is a big advantage in multiplayer, of course), but you need to cross the booster track for this to work.